# Google Admob native ads

Tags: android, admob

I implemented Admob native ad express into my application, following [this](https://youtu.be/LZCZSeFTvyk) video that was posted on google developers YouTube channel. Apon finishing it I read that it was discontinued since October 2017 and will stop being served in March 2018.

I can't find any information about this and what we as developers should do. Should we replace it with banner ads, native ads advance or what? I can't imagine having banner ads in a `RecyclerView` and there is also not a lot of information out there about impending native advanced ads in a `RecyclerView`.

Has anyone come across this issue and what did you do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right, [Native Ads Express](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/advanced) is being deprecated.

I guess you can try integrating [Native Ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/start) or [Native Ads Advanced](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/start)
.

Here are some examples of Native Ads in a `RecyclerView` that I found on [github](https://web.archive.org/web/20170804022212/https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ads/tree/master/advanced/NativeExpressRecyclerViewExample), [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37934671/admob-native-ads-in-recyclerview) and [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH9ZwRkGKoE).

Comment: Thank you for answering, but the examples you gave are all Native Ads Express. I managed to get a workaround for the by using a different ad provider.

Comment: @ClassA can you please share the workaround since the native advanced ads are not available for production.

Comment: @Records I'm not at my pc right now, I will provide a answer asap

Comment: @ClassA thanks, I'm literally waiting for your response to proceed, life or death situation haha.

Comment: @Records Haha.. I used Appodeal, you can look at the docs and they have great support..

Comment: @ClassA thanks alot will definitely take a look, any idea of average CPM.